# Proguard - Build Android with roboguice-sherlock and sherlock

Tags: android, maven, actionbarsherlock, proguard, roboguice

I am trying to build by android application using the **proguard-maven-plugin** but unfortunately i have some problems.

I am using the **roboguice-sherlock** and the **actionbarsherlock** libraries and i am getting the following warnings:

```
 [proguard] Warning: library class com.github.rtyley.android.sherlock.roboguice.activity.RoboSherlockActivity extends or implements program class com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity
 [proguard] Warning: library class com.github.rtyley.android.sherlock.android.accounts.SherlockAccountAuthenticatorActivity extends or implements program class com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity
 [proguard] Warning: library class com.github.rtyley.android.sherlock.roboguice.activity.RoboSherlockFragmentActivity extends or implements program class com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity
 [proguard] Warning: library class com.github.rtyley.android.sherlock.roboguice.activity.RoboSherlockListActivity extends or implements program class com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListActivity
 [proguard] Warning: library class com.github.rtyley.android.sherlock.roboguice.activity.RoboSherlockPreferenceActivity extends or implements program class com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockPreferenceActivity
 [proguard] Warning: library class com.github.rtyley.android.sherlock.roboguice.fragment.RoboSherlockDialogFragment extends or implements program class com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockDialogFragment
 [proguard] Warning: library class com.github.rtyley.android.sherlock.roboguice.fragment.RoboSherlockFragment extends or implements program class com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment
 [proguard] Warning: library class com.github.rtyley.android.sherlock.roboguice.fragment.RoboSherlockListFragment extends or implements program class com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment
 [proguard] Warning: there were 8 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
 [proguard]          You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
 [proguard]          be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
 [proguard]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)
 [proguard] Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

As i understand the roboguice-sherlock library references to the actionbarsherlock library which the plugin supposed that is program code.

Does anyone knows how i can overcame this problem?

Comment: Can you provide your proguard configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

Do you try with - dontwarn instruction on your proguard configuration file?

```
-dontwarn com.github.rtyley.android.sherlock.roboguice.**
```